# Repeat Text on pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, page-layout, typesetting

I need to repeat a text box on multiple pages in Indesign. The text is a model number so I want to type it in once on page one and it repeats on other pages. However it would not be in the same location on other pages. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE @WaynePatt. Do you have an example of what you are trying to do? I’m not sure I understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

1. You type that text on a master page.
2. You apply that master page to any pages in the document you need to use this text on.
3. Then, for each page, you CTRL+Click that text box to unlock it, then move it around and reposition where needed.